# Is every image of a loop in Hausdorff space, homeomorphic to $S^1$?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Let $S^1$ be the 1-sphere with respect to the standard norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space and $\alpha:[0,1]\rightarrow X$ be a loop.

Define $C=\alpha([0,1])$.

Define $q:[0,1]\rightarrow S^1:t\mapsto (\cos 2\pi t, \sin 2\pi t)$.

Then, $q$ is a quotient map. Also, $\alpha:[0,1]\rightarrow C$ is a quotient map.

Since, for each $t,s\in [0,1]$, $q(t)=q(s)$ implies that $\alpha(t)=\alpha(s)$, these induce a homeomorphism $h:S^1\rightarrow C$ such that $h\circ q= \alpha$.

Hence $C$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$.

Is my argument really true?

I'm not confident with myself since if this is really true, I don't get the usual definition of Jordan curve.

The standard definition for a Jordan curve is an image of an **injective** continuous map $\Phi:S^1\rightarrow X$ where $X$ is a topological space.

However, if my above argument is true, this definition is superfluous since it is equivalent to assuming there is a continuous map not necessarily injective

Comment: Consider a figure eight?

Comment: A homeomorphism must be bijective. Why do you think that the induced map $h$ would be injective? It isn't unless $\alpha$ is injective save for $\alpha(0)=\alpha(1)$. If $\alpha(t_1)=\alpha(t_2)$ where $\{t_1,t_2\}\neq\{0,1\}$ then $h(q(t_1))=h(q(t_2))$ but $q(t_1)\neq q(t_2)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What does "loop" mean?

If it does not require injectivity, then the result is obviously false with any constant loop $f:S^1\to X$ defined by $f(s)=x$ for all $s\in S^1$.

If it **does** require injectivity, then it is a general result that a continuous injection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space must be a homeomorphism onto its image.

However, either way, your argument is flawed. Given a continuous function $\alpha:X\to Z$ that descends along a quotient map $q:X\to Y$, the induced map $h:Y\to Z$ need not be a homeomorphism.

Comment: Which part of my argument is wrong?

Comment: If $q:X\rightarrow Y$ and $\alpha:X\rightarrow Z$ are quotient maps and if [$\forall x,y\in X$, $q(x)=q(y) \Rightarrow \alpha(x)=\alpha(y)$], then we can always construct a homeomorphism $h:Y\rightarrow Z$ such that $h\circ q= \alpha$.

Comment: $\alpha:[0,1]\rightarrow C$ is, of course, closed. And it is continuous surjection. Doesn't this condition imply that $\alpha$ is a quotient map? And just EDITED the comment above!

Comment: it is a theorem in Munkres topology p.142 Corollary 22,3

Comment: @Rubertos: I have edited my objection to your argument. For an algebraic analogue, consider a group homomorphism $f:G\to H$ that descends to a homomorphism $\varphi:G/K\to H$ for some $K\trianglelefteq G$. Unless $K=\ker(f)$ this $\varphi$ will not be injective. Similarly the induced map $h:S^1\to X$ from your loop $\alpha:[0,1]\to X$ has no particular reason to be injective.